# Chrome renders html table cell size differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

In below table (screenshot of chrome dev tools)

[image]

the column with `#` is filling 1317 pixels on X axis. As a table element should just require amount of space equal to text element then this should be much less, approx 50 pixels.

In IE11 the amount of space required is much less, why is Chrome rendering this differently ?

Comment: Usually chrome does not render that way! Could you please post a jsFiddle Link?

Comment: Or just add the HTML and relevant CSS to your questions perhaps?

Comment: Can you please post the entire table and css in your question or a fiddle please (or at least a minimal example which reproduces the same issue)? This looks like an issue based on the `display type / table layout` set on the table and also the content used in the cells.